# how to show data from exctract($_POST) to postman

Tags: php, api

i want to display data from api wablas using extract($_POST) to postman
i take it code from api wablas

```
/**
 * all data POST sent from https://console.wablas.com
 * you must create URL what can receive POST data
 * we will sent data like this: 
 * id = message ID - string
 * phone
 * status = status of message - string
 * device_id = device ID - string
 */
extract($_POST);
```

Comment: What is the question or what issue are you having? You should read security warning about the function you're trying to use `Warning
Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).`

Comment: the question is i want to receive POST data using postman

Comment: What do you mean by "receive POST data"? As Postman is a client, it does only receive what you put in your response, and the documentation is pretty clear about what `extract` does

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

It will show all data in array!

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

var_dump can dump all data